# How to pass value from nested if statmant in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new at programing, and I wanted to ask question. It seems that I cant pass values from nested if statments and global values dont work in flask. I'm a bit confused and would like to get some help

```
@app.route("/app_main_page/preke/<int:p_id>",  methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def viena_preke(p_id):
    form = UpdateItemForm()
    preke = Preke.query.get(p_id)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.prekes_nuotrauka.data:
            file = save_pict(form.prekes_nuotrauka.data)
        preke.pavadinimas = form.pavadinimas.data
        preke.apibudinimas = form.apibudinimas.data
        preke.author = current_user
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Jusu preke buvo atnaujinta", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("visos_prekes"))
    else:
        form.pavadinimas.data = preke.pavadinimas
        form.apibudinimas.data = preke.apibudinimas
    return render_template("VienaPreke.html", title="Viena preke", preke=preke, form=form, image = file)
```

I'm trying to run image file trough function to reduse size and change name of the file. But I always get "Unresolved reference 'file'", because the flask seems not to recognise value from nested if statment.

Error

> return render_template("VienaPreke.html", title="Viena preke", preke=preke, form=form, image = file) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment

Comment: Can you please provide the error trace in full? Btw, I assume in your case, you are receiving that error because the if statement doesn't execute and thus the variable is not set. Therefore, when you use that varaible, you get the `"Unresolved reference 'file'"` error

Comment: No. if statment execute, image name is change to Hex and image is resized, from that function i should recive new name of the file, since it is changed in  Hex numbers i dont know new name of the file.... Its intresting because if i use from flask-user a current_user.something its works good

Comment: return render_template("VienaPreke.html", title="Viena preke", preke=preke, form=form, image = file)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment

Comment: The error happens in a case when the call is made in a none-form submit request. In that case, the `file` is referenced before assignment. It works in the case you suggested since it will be assigned i.e. the if statement executes

Comment: Is this condition always met? `if form.prekes_nuotrauka.data:
            file = save_pict(form.prekes_nuotrauka.data)`
What if it's not? What value willl file get in that case?

Comment: Its a update to database. There already is a default image, so nothing happens if i dont specify except.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Just needed to learn how to use global variables(its not that easy as it seems). You need to assign value x before function, then you need to say global x in function and then you assign value to variable.